# Construction of a function from $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}\to \mathbb R^\Gamma $ where $\Gamma =\mathbb R^2/_\sim$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $\sim$ an equivalence relation, and denote $\Gamma=\mathbb R^2/_\sim$ the quotient space. We denote $\pi:\mathbb R^2\to \Gamma $ the natural projection. And now I want to identify $\mathbb R^\Gamma $ with $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}$ in a natural way.

Is there a natural way map from a set $A$ and $\mathbb R^A$ so that I can define easily the map $\mathbb R^{\Gamma }\to \mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}$ or the map $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}\to \mathbb R^\Gamma $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$g\mapsto g\circ\pi$$ serves as prescription of a map: $$\mathbb R^{\Gamma}\to\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}$$

Comment: What do you mean by prescription map ? Surprinsingly, this way doesn't really look natural for me... Normally, I would go from $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}\to \mathbb R^\Gamma $ (like for the projection...)

Comment: I do not call it a "prescription map" but just a map. Every map can be described/defined by means of a prescription. The map in my answer sends element $g\in\mathbb R^{\Gamma}$ to element $g\circ\pi\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb R^2}$. A natural map in other direction is - I think - not possible. You can at most define a natural map $B\to\mathbb R^{\Gamma}$ where $B$ denotes the subset containing functions $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ that respect $\sim$ in the sense that $x\sim y\implies f(x)=f(y)$. For every such $f$ a unique $g$ exists with $f=g\circ\pi$.